# User with 11 rep showing as participating in suggested edits review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits

I noticed this doing review just now. A user with 11 rep is showing as having participated in reviewing suggested edits. Obiviously this is not high enough rep to do so, but also this user shouldn't be able to have an expandable badge on hover like this, if I understand that feature correctly.

Am I not understanding the recent reviewers list?

[image]

Comment: He reviewed a [suggested edit to his own post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3108234).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Didn't realize how that worked.